# Is there an olive oil brand named "Orci" in Spain?

Tags: olive-oil, spanish-cuisine

Is there an olive oil brand named "Orci" in Spain? How is its extra virgin olive oil? I can't find anything related on the "Internet" in China. Some products near their bbds or expires are being sold inexpensively on PDD. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the 3rd image you can read

> packed by Aceites del Sur

a quick internet search returns a [Spanish company with that name](https://acesur.en.ecplaza.net/)

> Our Group has been active for more than 150 years producing, packing and marketing olive oil and other vegetable oils, as well as olive pates and vinegar products. This accumulated experience reinforces as a leading group within the national olive oil sector in Spain, also exporting its products to more than 90 countries around the world.
> Founded in 1840 our group has always been related to tradition, dedication, innovation and love of olive oil. Nowadays, we have a very professional workforce with more than 1000 people and many worldwide consolidated brands.
> We produce Spanish Olive Oil on these modalities: Extra Virgin, Olive and Pomace Olive Oil. Also we produce other oils as grape seed oil, sunflower oil, etc…
> Formats: Glass, Plastic and Tins
> References: 0.25 L, 0.50 L, 0.75 L, 1 L, 3 L, 5 L, 1000 L and 23.000 L.
> Our olive oil is produced according to national and international quality standards and all this confirmed by quality certificates.
> Quality is the main goal of Acesur. Our production process complies with the highest quality standard regulations and all our facilities are certified and environmentally compatible.
> Production processes are controlled by more than 20 analysts. We count on the most advanced managing techniques such as the revolutionary two milling phases for olive oil crushing. All our facilities are audited and certified by institutions like AENOR, AENOR Environmental Management, BRC and IFS.

The decently made site, the absence of typos and other obvious "autotranslate" feature seems to put them above the average Chinese internet shop level.

About the brand itself, "orci" is Italian, plural of "orcio", name used to indicate a pottery jar with a hole at the bottom, used to store liquid, usually oil or wine.

It's probably used because it sounds Spanish enough for the ears of the Chinese market.

Comment: Thanks. https://www.ecplaza.net/orci--product?listType=list returns nothing about orci

Comment: Is orci evoo sold in Spain?

Comment: @Tim - https://www.ecplaza.net/products/oem-service-spanish-olive-oil-3298549 - that looks like your orci bottle, doesn't it?  You can order a 20-foot container of olive oil with whatever brand name you want stuck on the label.

Comment: @KelvinSherlock Thanks. Is the quality of OEM EVOO worse, compared to that of branded by the same packing company?