# How good is the quality of OEM extra virgin olive oil compared to that of a known brand by the same packing company?

Tags: olive-oil

How good is the quality of OEM extra virgin olive oil compared to that of a known brand by the same packing company?
For example, [Acesur](https://acesur.en.ecplaza.net/) has a well known brand La Espanola. It also makes available [OEM services](https://www.ecplaza.net/products/oem-service-spanish-olive-oil-3298549). How is the quality of its OEM evoo compared to that of its own brand? See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/127932/

Does a/the company that provides the OEM services complete packaging oil into bottles and sealing the bottles, while its clients only need to creat their own labels to stick to the exterior of the bottles?  Isn't that more appropriately called ODM than OEM?

Does the quality of its OEM oil that is available to end consumers depend on and vary with the clients of its OEM oil?

Comment: I would expect that to be a question of what kind of service is ordered by the customer - the one using the service, not the consumer. I am not sure if this is within our scope, tbh. Your questions about olive oils have been skirting very close to what is considered shopping advice.

Answer (score 2):

Most olive oil producers have a number of grades and styes of olive oil, from low grade 'I can taste a bit of olive if I use my imagination' oil to super high quality 'OMG I didn't realize anything could taste like that' oil. Some may offer less refined cloudy products, some may offer medical grades as well.

OEM oil services are how most store brands are produced, and have a very wide range of quality based on the price point the store wants to sell the oil at. A cheap and cheerful grocery store would want a cheaper and lower quality oil, which may be lower than the quality of the bottom of that OEM producer's range, while a top end luxury supermarket chain would want something closer to premium to warrant the cost they'll sell it at.

As to whether the producer would make an OEM product better than their own flagship products there's no way to say, it would be a business decision based on how precious they are about their own brand.

By the way, labeling is usually part of the service these companies offer, so customers don't even have to stick a label on. Label art is usually supplied by the customer, I wouldn't expect an olive oil manufacturer to offer label design services, but some of the larger ones that are part of huge international conglomerates might.

Comment: There have been a few reports that many of the ‘flavorful’ olive oils sold to Americans are that way because they’re starting to go rancid.  So it’s possible that a packager might take the questionable oil in their tanks and use it to fill bottles with someone else’s name on it, even if it might have been higher quality oil originally

Comment: Specific example: Santini makes their own 100% pure Italian EV olive oil, which is one of the better middle-tier oils out there.  They also make a second, OEM variety for Trader Joe's, which contains a blend of discount-OO-market oils from all over Europe.  The TJ's store brand oil is definitely two steps in quality below their brand-name oil, because TJ's is mostly concerned with price.